# Calculate the taylor series of $f(x,y,z)=x^2(\sin y +3e^z)$

Tags: taylor-expansion

how can I calculate the taylor series to the 3rd-order of the following function:

$$f:\mathbb{R}^3\to\mathbb{R}, x\mapsto x^2(\sin y+3e^z)$$

at the point (1,0,0)?

Answer (score 1):

Just use the formula. [Here](http://www.math.ucdenver.edu/~esulliva/Calculus3/Taylor.pdf) you can find the multivariable Taylor polynomial formula (it is truncated after the quadratic term, but you can figure out the next one I'm sure).

There's not much to it, just sort of tedious calculation of derivatives.